# how to store retrieve data into CSV format

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having a problem while storing the data into a CSV file it is not storing properly.

```
import urllib2
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://contentlinks.dionglobal.in/ib/closeprices.asp?Exchange=NSE&Startname=A'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

for name_box in soup.find_all('tr', class_='alternate'):
    name = name_box.text.strip()
    print(name)

    with open('Book1.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([name])

for namebox2 in soup.find_all('tr', class_='alternate1'):
    name3 = namebox2.text.strip()

    with open('Book1.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([name3])

    print(type(name3))
```

Comment: Consider using ``pandas.read_html()``. It may solve all at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `pandas` for this task:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url='http://contentlinks.dionglobal.in/ib/closeprices.asp?Exchange=NSE&Startname=A'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

df = pd.read_html(str(soup.find_all('table', cellspacing=2)),skiprows=1,header=0)[0].dropna()
df.to_csv('Book1.csv',index=False)
```

the output is:

> ```
> Security Name     Open Pr         High Pr         Low Pri         Close P         Traded          Number          Traded Value (R
>
> 20 Microns        39.4            39.9            38.2            38.35           41131           203             1585478.1      
> 3i Infotech       4.25            4.4             4.15            4.15            3465068         1332            14679467.7     
> 3M India          13849.4         13899.9         13701.1         13732.8         3559            358             48934409.85    
> A2Z Mainten       45              45.15           42.75           43.15           896729          4280            39108262.2     
> Aarti Drug        521             533             506.6           530.3           23832           1516            12430577.4     
> Aarti Inds        940             943.95          916             923.45          184109          3043            172642406      
> Aarve Denim       64.5            65.95           61.05           61.4            19461           258             1216503.8      
> Aban Offshor      187.8           191.9           183.3           187.15          1705780         20844           322208420.1    
> ABB               1502            1506            1424.05         1443.35         108282          3793            156994217.4    
> Abbott India      4389            4389            4275            4298.35         873             331             3773028.6      
> ABG Shipyard      12.6            12.6            12.5            12.6            40626           126             511837.6       
> ABM Intl          113.05          113.05          102.35          106.35          3451            52              374868.15      
> Abshek Inds       80.8            81.3            77.8            79.1            418308          5783            33137029.05    
> ACC               1653.9          1655.95         1626.4          1636.7          171707          11603           281527492.6    
> Accel Front       51.1            51.1            48.3            50              6608            17              334956
> ```